# Can you put multiple gems into the Gumball ship's equipment?

Tags: lovers-in-a-dangerous-spacetime

In [Lovers in a Dangerous Spacetime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lovers_in_a_Dangerous_Spacetime) I have received three different types of gems inside little presents:

> - power gems
>  - beam gems
>  - metal gems

In the early game (Ursa Major campaign) can more than one gem be added to the ship's equipment? I can't exactly determine what happens, because

> I put a Beam gem into the shied, and it started reflecting bolts back at the enemy, but then when I tried to add a Power gem to the shield also, I couldn't determine if the Power gem simply *replaced* the Beam gem, or if it was additive.
>  
>  Wikipedia says that "Creatures saved count towards improving the effectiveness of the ship by allowing two gems per station", and I can't tell if that needs to be unlocked by saving more bunnies.

Can you put multiple gems into the Gumball ship's equipment during the Ursa Major campaign?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this game, you'll be able to do campaigns again after completion. Based on how many lovers you saved, you'll be able to unlock different upgrades.

So, you *can* combine gems in this campaign, but only after playing a bit. On a first run I don't think that's really doable.